# SQL get to select multiple names from select subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing select statement in SQL Server. I have to add a select query.

```
select 
    acct.AccountID,
    acct.Username,
    acct.LastNm + ', ' + acct.FirstNm as Name ,
    acct.Lastlogin,
    acct.email as Email,
    (select acct2.FirstNm + ' ' + acct2.LastNm as Name from tblUserAccount acct2
              join tblReviewers ra2 on acct2.AccountID = ra2.ReviwerID) as Reviewers

from tblUserAccount acct
```

I need to get more names from a table called tblReviwers. So 1 user from the tblUserAccount table could be associated with multiple reviews.

The tblReviewers only has 3 column AnalystID, ReviewerID, and Date. When I select on the JOIN between TblUserAccount and TblReviewers on a test AccountID = AnalystID, I can get multiple ReviewerIDs, which their firstname and lastname are located in the tblUserAccount. This is the reason why I use a select subquery

When I run the query, I get the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I am trying to write a VIEW to get a data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: join to that derived table (your sub query) or in that case, just join to the tblReviewers  account like normal. no need for a subquery or derived table here i wouldn't think but sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: Please clarify: if e.g. a `tblUserAccount` record has 5 entries in `tblReviewers`, do you want **1 output row** that includes a computed column containing all 5 reviewers (e.g. as a comma-separated string), or do you want **5 output rows** (each of which repeats the `tblUserAccount` info + data from one of the `tblReviewers` rows)?

Comment: HI, If a user has 5 reviewers, I like to get 1 row with that 1 user and 5 reviewers. I been googling for writeout XML for those multiple reviewers but not sure how.

Comment: Also `tblReviewers` must contain two account ids. One in the role a the reviewer and one in the role of the reviewed. Only Then you can formulate this m-to-n relation.

Comment: what the structure of tblReviewers?

Comment: The tblReviewers only has 3 column AnaystID, ReviewerID, and Date. When I select on the JOIN between TblUserAccount and TblReviewers on a test AccountID = AnalystID, I can get multiple ReviewerID, which their firstname and lastname are located in the tblUserAccount. This is the reason why I use a select subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query for a column name can only contain a single record result set.  If you have an entry with multiple results causes that error.

I think you are missing disclosure of a possible extra component needed in the reviewers table, the who entered it.  This will result in a query similar to the following.

The aliases and relations will appear obvious, but need to be confirmed for your actual structure.

```
select 
      EnterBy.AccountID,
      EnterBy.Username,
      EnterBy.LastNm + ', ' + EnterBy.FirstNm as Name ,
      EnterBy.Lastlogin,
      EnterBy.email as Email,
      ReviewBy.FirstNm + ' ' + ReviewBy.LastNm as ReviewerName
   from 
      tblReviewers r
         tblUserAccount EnterBy
            on r.AccountID = EnterBy.AccountID
         tblUserAccount ReviewBy
            on r.ReviwerID = ReviewBy.AccountID
```

**REVISION BASED ON ADDITIONAL DATA**

Based on providing the analystID on who entered, you should be good with

```
select 
      EnterBy.AccountID,
      EnterBy.Username,
      EnterBy.LastNm + ', ' + EnterBy.FirstNm as Name ,
      EnterBy.Lastlogin,
      EnterBy.email as Email,
      STUFF(( Select 
                    ', [' + ReviewBy.LastNm + ', ' + ReviewBy.FirstNm + '] ' AS [text()]
                 From
                    tblReviewers r
                       JOIN tblUserAccount ReviewBy
                          on r.ReviwerID = ReviewBy.AccountID
                 where
                    r.AnaylstID  = EnterBy.AccountID
                 For XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '' ) as AllReviewers
   from 
      tblUserAccount EnterBy
```

Comment: Hi, tblReviewers table does not have a firstNm and LastNm. It only have the AnaylstID which the name can be found in tblUserAccount which is why I add the subquery. –

Comment: @c0micrage, done as single query using STUFF() under Microsoft SQL-Server.  However, with multiple people, and your desired names listed as last, first... the result of reviewers will be "last, first, last, first, last, first, etc...." for as many reviewers.  You may want to add square brackets such as ', [' + … + ']' to better wrap as '[last, first], [last, first], etc...'

Comment: @c0micrage, you are welcome, be sure to click the checkbox to mark as solved so future people know what worked under their possible similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a column that contains multiple rows in a single result set, it just doesn't make sense from SQL perspective. Hence the error.

You should `JOIN` the `tblReviewers` table instead of subselecting it. That will yield all Reviewers. Then, `JOIN` again on the `tblUserAccount` table to get the name of the Reviewer, and you are all set.

```
SELECT 
    acct.AccountID,
    acct.Username,
    acct.LastNm + ', ' + acct.FirstNm as Name ,
    acct.Lastlogin,
    acct.email as Email,
    acct2.LastNm + ', ' + acct2.FirstNm as ReviewerName ,
FROM tblUserAccount acct
JOIN tblReviewers revi
    ON on acct.AccountID = revi.ReviewerID
JOIN tblUserAccount acct2
    ON on acct2.AccountID = revi.AnalystID
```

Comment: Hi, tblReviewers table does not have a firstNm and LastNm. It only have the AnaylstID which the name can be found in tblUserAccount which is why I add the subquery.

Comment: @c0micrage : OK then, updated my answer accordingly, that should do it !

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Sql Server 2017, You can use something like STRING_AGG function, which combines values from multiple rows into a single string.

Then, your Reviewers column in your query might look like this:

```
(select STRING_AGG(Name, ',') from
    (select acct2.FirstNm + ' ' + acct2.LastNm as Name from tblUserAccount acct2
     join tblReviewers ra2 on acct2.AccountID = ra2.ReviwerID
     where ra2.AnalystID = acct.AccountID)
) as Reviewers
```

In this case, names(first name + last name) of the reviewers for the current user will be separated by commas.

Comment: Nice new feature to SQL-Server, but unsure the version they are running and if that version supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Subselects in select lists can only be used to return one value.

In your case, use joins

```
SELECT
    a.AccountID,
    a.Username,
    a.LastNm + ', ' + a.FirstNm as Name ,
    a.Lastlogin,
    a.email as Email,
    b.LastNm + ', ' + b.FirstNm as ReviewerName
FROM
    tblUserAccount a
    LEFT JOIN tblReviewers r ON a.AccountID = r.AnalystID
    INNER JOIN tblUserAccount b ON r.ReviewerID = b.AccountID
```

I also used a LEFT JOIN to the reviewers table, in case there is no reviewer defined for an analyst.

You will get several rows per analyst, if more than one reviewer is assigned to it. Usually I solve this problem in the front-end by making a report that puts the main data in a group header (the analyst) and the related date (the reviewers) in the detail section of the report.

---

Starting with SQL Server 2017, you can also use the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to concatenate the values of string expressions.

```
SELECT
    a.AccountID,
    a.Username,
    a.LastNm + ', ' + a.FirstNm AS Name ,
    a.Lastlogin,
    a.email AS Email,
    STRING_AGG(
        ( SELECT b.LastNm + ' ' + b.FirstNm
          FROM
              tblReviewers
              INNER JOIN tblUserAccount b ON r.ReviewerID = b.AccountID
          WHERE
              r.AnalystID =  a.AccountID ),
        ', ') AS ReviewerName
FROM
    tblUserAccount a
```

This allows you to return more than one reviewer in one field.